# Typeahead.js trouble - Suggestions not appear

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

Here is my js code to execute typeahead:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.search-field.input').typeahead({
        name: 'group-static',
        prefetch: 'http://ws.luyencong.net/data/search/query.php?do=advanced',
        header: '<span class="group-title">General Content</span>',
        template: [
        '<img class="icon" src="{{icon}}" style="width: 38px; height: 38px" />',
        '<div class="icon-desc"><span xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="title">{{name}}</span>',
        '<span xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="desc">{{description}}</span></div>',
        '<span class="clear"></span>'
        ].join(''),
        engine: Hogan
    });
});
```

Typeahead is executed (Because I can see tt-hint input, and the wrapper of suggestion div)
But there is a trouble, when I type a character, the suggestion is not display as it must to be.

My JSON is located at : http://ws.luyencong.net/data/search/query.php?do=advanced

Please give me some helps. Thanks.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: No, the JSON file is `GET` normally (but idk why it was red but it is not an error when i filter by) You can check http://www.luyencong.net

Comment: What do you mean when you "filter by"? Looks like the issue is due to you making a cross-domain request. If at all possible, serve the JSON from `luyencong.net`, not `ws.luyencong.net`.

Comment: Is this correct if I change prefect url to `/ws/data/search/query.php?do=advanced`

I mean filter Error in Console (Firebug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a typeahead.js issue. The issue is that you are making a cross-domain request from `luyencong.net` to `ws.luyencong.net`. If you can, host the prefetch JSON file on `luyencong.net` – that's probably the easiest solution.

```
jQuery('.search-field.input').typeahead({
  // ...
  prefetch: 'http://luyencong.net/data/search/query.php?do=advanced'
  // ...
});
```

If you can't do that, there are some other options:

- [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)
- [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)